# Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list during firebase authentication

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

```
ll.firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword( email : 'emai@gmail.com' , password : 'password' )
```

I am trying to sign in with this code and it is giving me an error as stated. I have checked multiple threads and they suggest a few options but they did not work for me.

Comment: what is "ll" in your code?

Comment: its the address to my firebase store

Comment: new LiveLinks('MY LIVE LINK STORE');

Answer (score 0):

Use the firebase projects details in your code and then instead of : user = in the code and it will work fine. Also with new firebase you do not need to assign variable to get the project name.